# Gas Cooking Hob

Tags: kitchen-safety

We are looking to buy a home (flat) in the coming months. We have a strong preference for a gas cooking hob but have found that most of the new developments have electric cooking hobs. We have heard of gas cylinders that can used for gas cooking but are not sure how safe it would be to keep highly inflammable propane gas cylinders in the kitchen. Can someone provide information on how safe it is to keep these cylinders in the kitchen, are they allowed legally here in UK, are there specially constructed cabinets required  for these cylinders, cost of these cylinders and how long they last etc.

Kind Regards
Ravi

Comment: I think they're typically butane, not propane.  And I think there's a similar question on here somewhere ...  wait, no.  It's related, but not useful to answer this ( http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10588/67 ) ... and cost is going to be very localized (and dependent on time, I suspect)

Comment: I think I found it : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18803/67

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a gas cooker but have no gas supply](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18803/need-a-gas-cooker-but-have-no-gas-supply)

Comment: There are probably regulations preventing you bringing gas into your apartment, either in your apartment block or the city; ask around; and have a looksie at induction hobs instead of gas.

Comment: Agreed w/ Max on the apartment regulations -- I once lived in an apartment complex that had a ban on outdoor grilling, after someone had a grill on their balcony and started a fire bad enough that they had to gut and rebuild most of that building. ... but I had a thought -- check your phone book (or electronic equivalent) for a local gas supply company.  They'll likely be able to point you in the right direction, or know if they're not allowed by the local council.

Comment: Also make sure there is enough ventilation. Otherwise you could get carbon monoxide build up, which is very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently in Vietnam and it standard practice here to have a gas cylinder under the kitchen counter that the gas appliance sits on. (I doubt there is any code here or the desire to comply with any code. They drive around in chaotic traffic with gas cylinders on the back of motor scooters to deliver them)

An alternative (if your flat is a house or town house )  is to have a large propane tank installed on the outside of you home and a gas line installed to the kitchen ( or heating appliance ) inside your home.  you can then have gas delivered to you and not have to deal with continued change outs of small gas cylinders.

Answer (score 0):

The cylinders are intended to be stored indoors. People who use them for camping often keep them in the loft, with significant temperature variation. Although they're a danger in a fire, at that point you've got bigger things to worry about like getting out.

Calor or CampingGaz of a few kilos would be adequate, especially if you only use the gas when you really want it (e.g. a gas wok burner) and stick to the electric stove the rest of the time. There are many types of electric cooker and some are better than you might think.

There aren't any legal issues, but if its a flat, there may be restrictions on doing this. I'm not an expert but it's something you should look into with your conveyancer if it's an essential.